# Cannot find module from local file in express js app

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, mern

I have an express js project generated with npm init, the stack is **(express mySql, sequelize)**, i am planing to do a mern stack starting out from doing backend first. For the database I use **MySQL** instead of MongoDB.

**The error**:
the error is `can't find module` from local file

**here is the snapshot of the error message**:
[image]

**the file structure**

[image]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "login_system",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.32.1"
  }
}
```

**index.js**  --> entry point

```
import express from "express";
import db from "./config/database.js";
import router from "./routes/index.js";

const app = express();

// create database connection 
try {
  await db.authenticate();
  console.log("Database Connected ...");
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}

app.use(express.json());
app.use(router);

app.listen(5000, () => console.log("server is running at port 5000"));
```

**routes/index.js**

```
import express from "express";
import getUser from "../controllers/Users"; --> this is where the error is

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/users", getUser);

export default router;
```

**controllers/Users.js** --> **'cannot find module'** error comes from this file

```
import users from "../models/UserModel";

const getUsers = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users_ = await users.findAll();
    res.json(users_);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export default getUsers;
```

Any Idea how to solve this error ? thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append `.js` to the import statements, for example:

```
import getUser from "../controllers/Users.js";

import users from "../models/UserModel.js";
```

As per Node [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions):

> A file extension must be provided when using the import keyword to resolve relative or absolute specifiers. Directory indexes (e.g. './startup/index.js') must also be fully specified.

Comment: Thankyou it works, thank you for the link to the docs, now I know that its mandatory to include the .js extension to resolve relative or absolute specifiers @jQueeny

Answer (score -1):

```
const getUsers = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users_ = await UserModel.findAll();
    res.json(users_);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
};

export default getUsers;
```

Replace users with UserModel, because Mongoose-based application, the term "UserModel" often refers to a Mongoose model that represents a schema and provides an interface for interacting with a MongoDB collection. So, in your context, if you're using Mongoose for your MongoDB interactions, the UserModel likely represents a schema and model for your "User" data.

Comment: Sorry for the missinformation. I dont use mongoDB, i use MySQL instead, so i think whether i use UserModel or not should work just fine @Anandateertha